# Modifier in "People of all ages enjoy swimming"?

Tags: modifiers

Consider the sentence:

> People of all ages enjoy swimming.

Here the solution says that the modifier is "of all ages". I want to understand why is "enjoy" not a modifier in the above sentence.

Comment: Because it's the predicate. If it were a modifier, you wouldn't *have* a sentence.

Comment: Why do you think *enjoy* might be a modifier here? What do you think it modifies?

Comment: "Of all ages" modifies  "people". "Enjoy" is a verb, so it can hardly be a modifier!

Answer (score 1):

At the core of all sentences are nouns and verbs.  Traditionally, nouns can be ‘qualified’ (generally by adjectives or adjective phrases).  But they can be ‘modified’ by adverbial phrases:  for example, “the woman outside Nero’s”.

Nouns cannot qualify anything.  They are ‘quafilyees’.  Well, for quite some time now, nouns are increasingly being used as if they were adjectives.  We speak of a ‘hat shop’ or ‘school day’.  So you could say that a noun could qualify another noun.  Though we normally think of ‘hat’ and ‘school, as nouns, they can be used as if they were adjectives.  This can happen.  So, if asked what part of speech ‘green’ is, I would say ‘adjective’.  But the ‘green’ in ‘bowling green’ is serving as a noun.

That does not convert nouns into fully-fledged adjectives, of course.  They do not acquire comparatives or superlatives, for example.  They tend to classify rather than ‘describe’ the nouns they qualify (or perhaps we should say ‘*modify*’).

So what about a verb:  the other core element of a sentence?  The old fashioned rule is that verbs are ***modified*** by *adverbs* (or by adverbial phrases).  They always have a subject and (unless they are either passive or intransitive) an object.  These do not modify the verb itself, because they do not alter in any way how the verb itself is understood.  Cooking is still just cooking, whoever cooks and whatever s/he cooks.  To modify, we talk about how or with what or for how long (etc...) s/he cooks.

Or is it not so simple?  Some parts  of verbs can be modifiers.  After all,

> the English language is ***frighteningly***  complicated.

There:  an adverb, formed from the verb ‘frighten’.  So it can modify another verb.

As you see, the adverb *frighteningly* is formed in the usual way from the **adjective** *frightening*, formed from the verb *frighten*, as before.  This time, the adverbial and adjectival forms behave just like other qualifiers and modifiers.  Things can be more or less frightening, and can happen more or less frighteningly.

There are other such verb forms:  *frightenable*, for example.

Now someone might say that I am cheating:  that these forms are not forms of the verb itself when it is acting as a verb with at least a subject.  So the rule has to be restated to exclude these forms, by stipulating that they are real adjectives (or adverbs) **formed from verbs**; or that verbs cannot modify (or qualify)**except when they are participles or so-called gerunds** .

From your point of view, you can treat the rule as a valid one in the sense that verbs that perform the key role of verbs in constructing a sentence cannot themselves be modifiers.

Answer (score 0):

*Enjoy* is the verb in the sentence.

*Swimming* is a gerund, a noun made from a verb. It's the thing the people enjoy.

Since *enjoy* is the verb here, it isn't considered a modifier.

Answer (score 0):

> People *of all ages* enjoy swimming.

In the above sentence, the (prepositional) phrase *of all ages* modifies the *People* who *enjoy swimming*.
Therefore, **enjoy** is not the part of the modifier. However, there are cases when a verb is used in a phrase that works as a modifier. For example;

> In all ages, there are people **who enjoy swimming**.

Comment: Your closing example adopts an interesting interpretation of the word *ages*, taking 'age' to mean 'era' (bronze age, the middle ages, the modern age, etc) instead of an individual's 'calendar' age (how old someone is).

Comment: This is not correct.  “Who enjoy swimming” is a relative clause, not a phrase.